# Calling Mailto inside body of another mailto

Tags: javascript, c#, vb.net

Is that possible to give mailto inside the body of another mailto?

I have vb.net code through which I am opening outlook window.

I have the below code,

```
sMsg = User.Redirect("mailto:" + legRev + "& CC=" + cc + "&Subject= " + OuterSubject + "&body=" + Body)
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.GetType(), "showalert", sMsg, True)

Public Function Redirect(ByVal PageName As String) As String
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("window.location.href='" + PageName + "'; ")
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

In the body string I have

```
mailto:" + innerTo + "&CC=" + innerCC + "&Subject= " + innerSubject
```

Problem is I am getting a mail opened with subject set to 'innerSubject' instead of 'OuterSubject'

I think my OuterSubject is getting replaced by InnerSubject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body string needs to be escaped with a function like `Uri.EscapeDataString`. Your URI should end up having only one `?` in it, and none of the `&` characters from your body should be visible.
Example:

```
mailto:john.doe@example.com?subject=Test+Message&body=mailto%3Ajane.doe%40example.com%3Fcc%3Dbob%40bob.com%26subject%3DReply%2Bto%2Byou
```